# Duplicate Analysis Using Python

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, data-analysis

I am a beginner in Python.

So far I have identified the duplicates using pandas lib but don't know how this will help me.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataframe = pd.read_csv("HKTW_INDIA_Duplicate_Account.csv")
dataframe.info()
name = dataframe["PARTY_NAME"duplicate_data=dataframe[name.isin(name[name.duplicated()])].sort_values("PARTY_NAME")
duplicate_data.head()
```

What I want: I have a set of data that is duplicated and I need to merge the duplicates based on certain conditions and need to populate the feedback in a new column.

I can do this manually also in Excel but the records are very high which will consume a lot of time. (More than 4,00,000 rows)

```
Primary Account ID  Secondary Account ID    Account Name    Translated Name    Created on Date    Amount Today   Amount Total   Split   Reamrks New ID
    1234                     245            Julia              Julia            24-May-20           530              45           N     
    2345                                    Julia              Julia            24-Sep-20                                         N     
    3456                      42            Sara               Sara             24-Aug-20           230                           Y     
    4567                                    Sara               Sara             24-Sep-20                                         Y     
    5678                                    Matt               Matt             24-Jun-20                                         N
    6789                                    Matt               Matt             24-Sep-20                                         N 
    7890                      58            Robert             Robert           24-Feb-20           525              21           N     
    1937                                    Robert             Robert           24-Sep-20                                         N     
    7854                      55            Robert             Robert           24-Jan-20           543              74           N
```

[image]

Conditions:

1. Only those accounts can be merged where we have "N" in Split Column and Amount_Total & Amount_Today is Blank.
   Expected Output:
   [image]
2. Value in Secondary_Account_ID or not.
   Example: Row 2 does not have any Secondary Registry ID and does not have any value in Amount_Total & Amount_Todat but Row 1 has the value in Secondary_Account_ID, so in this case, Row 2 can be merged to Row 1 because both have the same name. In the remarks columns, it should give me Winner account have secondary id(row 2 & row 1) and copy the Account ID from row 1 and paste in (row 2 & row 1) (Column "New ID")
   Expected Output:
   [image]
3. If duplicate accounts have Amount_Total and Amount_Today then it should not be merged.
   Expected Output:
   [image]
4. If duplicate accounts do not have any value in Secondary_Account_ID then it will check for Amount_today or Amount_total column, if the value is there in these two columns then the account which does not have values in these two columns will be merged to another one.
   Expected Output:
   [image]
5. If more the one duplicate account has a Secondary ID and if Amount_Today or Amount_Total is available for one account then that account will be considered as a winner account.
   Expected Output:
   [image]
6. If more the one duplicate account has a Secondary ID and if Amount_Today or Amount_Total is available for more than one account then that account which has the maximum value in Amount_Total will be considered as winner account.
   Expected Output:
   [image]
7. If Secondary_Account_ID, Total_Amount, and Today_Amount is blank then it should consider the oldest account.
   Expected Output:
   [image]

Comment: Please add data as text, not images. Additionally, the question needs to be more focused. Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as text**. Only plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi Trenton,

Thank you for your kind suggestion,

I have updated the data in the text format.

Comment: please add your dataframe as pd.Dataframe() format, then I can put it into my IDE